# editing roles with edit_role discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have the following line in my script:

```
await client.edit_role(server='547874634978789398', role='' ,colour=0x008000)
```

However I do not understand what parameter discord.py is expecting for `role=`. Can anyone point me in the right direction to better understand this parameter?

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.edit_role).  `role` is the role you want to edit

Comment: @PatrickHaugh can you give me an exsample?

Comment: What do you know about the role you want to edit?  name, id, etc?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh i have all of that, i dont understand which to enter into role='   '

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use `Server` class not server's id. There is `get_server()` function that returns `Server` object with the given server's id.

```
server = client.get_server('547874634978789398')
```

Then, you can access to all roles belonging to the server by `server.roles`. It is `list` of `Role` object. So if you have a name of role and want to edit one's role into that, try it.

```
for role in server.roles:
    if role.name == 'role_name':
        # What you want to do.
        await client.edit_role(server=server, role=role, colour=0x0080000)
        break
```

Also there is `server.role_hierarchy` property which returns roles in order of the hierarchy. It contains same elements with `server.roles` but it is the sorted version.

Answer (score 0):

```py
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Name")
# This will get the role you want to edit
await role.edit(color=0x008000, reason="The reason")
# This will edit the role with the desired color
```

For more information on this please see the docs: [discord.Role.edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.edit) | [discord.utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)

Comment: This is for the updated rewrite, just thought I would send an update because I was also looking for an answer.